# Use variable name in mongoDB expression (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use the value of a variable in a mongo expression as you can see below:

```
DbModels.prototype.findByParam = function(_collection, param, id, callback) {
    this.getCollection(_collection, function(error, sel_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        sel_collection.findOne({param.toString(): id}, function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result);
        });
      }
    });
};
```

However, the param.toString() gives an error. Any suggestions how I can use the value of the param variable in the mongoDb expression?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the value of param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax `{param.toString(): id}` is not valid.

Try

```
var query = {};
query[param.toString()] = id;
sel_collection.findOne(query, function(error, result) {
  if( error ) callback(error)
  else callback(null, result);
});
```